# Mock-Server - Custom object as REST response

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, integration-testing, mockserver

I'm using Mock-Server (mock-server.com) in version 5.10.0 for mocking a REST-API in a JUnit 5 test. I'm developing a spring-boot application with Java 8. My payload format is "protobuf" and so my REST interface is returning a `ResponseEntity<MyProtoObject>`. Unfortunately I can't find a built-in solution in Mock-Server that custom objects are returned by the Mock-Server as body. I only found methods like `withBody(String)` or `withBody(byte[])`. In addition to that methods I found a method `withBody(BodyWithContentType)`. I tried to create the following implementation/usage of the abstract class `BodyWithContent<T>` in my unit testclass:

```
private final class MyProtoObjectPayloadBody extends BodyWithContentType<MyProtoObject> {

    public MyProtoObjectPayloadBody () {
        super(null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public MyProtoObject getValue() {
        // return logic of MyProtoObject
    }
}

// Called in @BeforeEach
private void prepareMock() {

    this.mockServer.when(HttpRequest.request().withMethod("GET").withPath("/my-path"))
                .respond(HttpResponse.response().withStatusCode(200).withBody(new MyProtoObjectPayloadBody ()).withDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 5));
}
```

When I debug my code where the ResponseEntity occurs I get the response from the mock server but the "body" of the response is always empty. My custom `getValue()` is never called, too. I ensured that the REST call result in my application logic comes from the mock server using different return codes.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I got the reply from the mock-server developer via Slack that it's not possible to return custom objects. It's unclear to the mock-server how they should be (de)serialized. So I'll try to use a workaround via byte[]

Answer (score 0):

You can return json response of your object as

```
mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.once(),
                  MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(<URL>))
            .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess(
                <json-response>, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```